# Javascript not adding selected values in radio buttons when running function

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a test website to learn some js by making an online store than basically has values in a form 
what i am stuck on is when my html calls the function on shipping 
its not adding the shipping properly (only for ground which seems to be defaulted to)
I need the ability for the script to calculate the proper shipping charge depending on radio button selected

```js
function calcTaxes() {
    cost = 10;
    var taxed = cost * document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var freight = document.getElementById("shipping").value;
    var freightNum = parseInt(freight, 10);
    var totalCost;
    
   
    if (taxed < 10){
        taxed = (taxed * .1) + taxed;
        totalCost = taxed + freightNum;
        document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "$" +totalCost;

    }
    else if (taxed > 10 && taxed < 20){
        taxed = (taxed * .0725) + taxed;
        totalCost = taxed + freightNum;
        document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "$" +totalCost;
    }
    else {
        taxed = (taxed * .05) + taxed;
        totalCost = taxed + freightNum;
        document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "$" +totalCost;
    }

}
```

```html
  <h2>Order Form -- T-shirts $10 each</h2>
        <br>
        <form>
            Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Your name here" ><br><br>
            Address: <textarea placeholder="Your Address"></textarea><br><br>
            Email: <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" ><br><br>
            <label for="size">Choose a size: (Same Price) </label>
            <select id="size" name="size">
                <option value="XS">XS -Extra Small</option>
                <option value="S">S-Small</option>
                <option value="M">M-Medium</option>
                <option value="L">L-Large</option>
                <option value="XL">XL-Extra Large</option>
                <option value="XXL">XXL-Extra Extra Large</option>
            </select><br><br>
            Color: <input type="radio" value="Black" name="color">Black
            <input type="radio" value="White" name="color">White
            <input type="radio" value="Gun-Metal" name="color">Gun-Metal 
            <br><br>
            Quantity: <input id="qty" type="number"><br><br>
            Shipping: <input type="radio" value= "10" id="shipping" name="shipp">Ground ($10)
            <input type="radio" value="20" id="shipping" name="shipp" >Overnight ($20)
            <input type="radio" value="25" id="shipping" name="shipp" >Drone-Drop ($25)
            <br><br>
        <br>
        
        </form>
            <button class="taxes" onclick="calcTaxes()">Calculate Total</button><br>
            Includes shipping and taxes:<p id="tax"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to get the value from the current selected radio button, for example, you could do:

`var freight = document.querySelector('input[name="shipp"]:checked').value;`

```js
function calcTaxes() {
  cost = 10;
  var taxed = cost * document.getElementById("qty").value;
  var freight = document.querySelector(`input[name="shipp"]:checked`)
    .value;

  var freightNum = parseInt(freight, 10);
  var totalCost;

  if (taxed < 10) {
    taxed = taxed * 0.1 + taxed;
    totalCost = taxed + freightNum;
    document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
  } else if (taxed > 10 && taxed < 20) {
    taxed = taxed * 0.0725 + taxed;
    totalCost = taxed + freightNum;
    document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
  } else {
    taxed = taxed * 0.05 + taxed;
    totalCost = taxed + freightNum;
    document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Order Form -- T-shirts $10 each</h2>
<br />
<form>
  Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Your name here" /><br /><br /> Address: <textarea placeholder="Your Address"></textarea><br /><br /> Email: <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" /><br /><br />
  <label for="size">Choose a size: (Same Price) </label>
  <select id="size" name="size">
    <option value="XS">XS -Extra Small</option>
    <option value="S">S-Small</option>
    <option value="M">M-Medium</option>
    <option value="L">L-Large</option>
    <option value="XL">XL-Extra Large</option>
    <option value="XXL">XXL-Extra Extra Large</option>
  </select><br /><br /> Color: <input type="radio" value="Black" name="color" />Black
  <input type="radio" value="White" name="color" />White
  <input type="radio" value="Gun-Metal" name="color" />Gun-Metal
  <br /><br /> Quantity: <input id="qty" type="number" /><br /><br /> Shipping:
  <input type="radio" value="10" id="shipping" name="shipp" />Ground ($10)
  <input type="radio" value="20" id="shipping" name="shipp" />Overnight ($20)
  <input type="radio" value="25" id="shipping" name="shipp" />Drone-Drop ($25) <br /><br />
  <br />
</form>
<button class="taxes" onclick="calcTaxes()">Calculate Total</button><br /> Includes shipping and taxes:
<p id="tax"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you Luis...It was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using document.getElementById which will always return the first element with I'd shipping.

Try using document.getElementsByName

Remember it'll return an array of elements

Answer (score 0):

So what I can see the freight value is being assigned the first value since it's calling the first id with the name `shipping` with `document.getElementById('shipping')`.

You could assign each radio button with an `onclick="myShippingCost(this.value)"` and in your JS, call that function if your main `calcTaxes()`.

Example:

```js
var radioValue;

myShippingCost(value) {
  radioValue = value;
}

calcTaxes() {
  // ...your code
  var freight = radioValue;
  // ...your code
}
```